# How to add terraform aws_cognito_user_pool_client access token and id token validity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito

In AWS Cognito Console, App Clients under "General Settings", there are 3 types of token expirations that can be customized:

- Refresh token expiration
- Access token expiration
- ID Token expiration

Based on [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool_client), the aws_cognito_user_pool_client resource has a "refresh_token_validity" attribute that I could use to specify the expiration time for refresh tokens. However, there's none for access token or ID token validity.

How can I specify those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason access and id token expiration attributes were not added due to lack of support from AWS.

AWS has added support for this on August 12, 2020. Implementation in Terraform has completed on March 9, 2021 via [github commit](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/14919). This feature is supported via Terraform AWS Provider v3.32.

Be sure to have your terraform provider updated to at least that version to be able to use these new attributes.